# Let $R = \mathbb{Q}[x]$ and let $I = (x^2 + 2x + 2)R$ be the principal ideal generated by $x^2 + 2x +2$. Two questions are below.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals, polynomial-congruences, division-ring

i) Show that any element of $R$ is congruent modulo $I$ to a unique polynomial of the form $ax+b$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$?

ii) Show that any element of the quotient ring $R/I$ is of the form $\widehat{ax+b}$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$?

I've attempted both questions.

For i) I use the division algorithm to show that for each polynomial $f(x) \in R$, there are unique polynomials $r(x), q(x) \in R$ such that

$$f(x) = q(x)(x^2+2x+2) + r(x)$$

where $r(x) = ax + b$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$.  Therefore $f(x) - r(x) \in I$ so $f(x)$ is congruent to $r(x)$ modulo $I$.

As for ii) I wrote that $\widehat{f(x)} = \widehat{r(x)}$ because the difference of the two coset representitives lies in $I$.  Therefore, $\widehat{f(x)} = \widehat{r(x)} = \widehat{ax+b}  \in R/I$.

Am I correct when answering both questions or have I left anything out?

Thank you

Comment: Yes it's correct. For unicity, you can argue with the uniqueness of the remainder and the uniqueness of $q(x)$.

Comment: @Surb Thank you! What do you mean but the unicity? I didn't realize you needed to comment on the uniqueness of $q(x)$.